# Problemas na identificação do arquivo com erros no dev tools do chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

Tenho uma página aspx, que pelo dev tools do chrome, me dá o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

O problema que ele aponta para essa linha:

> prs0101.aspx.561

Acontece que nesse arquivo não tem a linha 561. Aí entendi que esse erro pode estar dando em algum arquivo javascript incluso. Bem, no momento do erro, na aba SOURCE, ele abre mais dois ambientes, o primeiro contendo três abas: SOURCE, CONTENT SCRIPTs e SNIPPETS. E a outra aba chamada script resource. Bem, vem em branco, quando eu clico na ABA SOURCE e depois na ABA SOURCE(Interna), me abre algumas pastas e uma onde parece estar o erro. Clico e me abre o js AjaxToolKit e vou até a página 561 e acho um comentário. Ainda não consegui entender onde realmente está o erro, não está claro. No IE é pior ainda. Como eu faço para ir até o erro usando o dev tools? Não sei se fui claro. À disposição.

Comment: Até onde sei quando chega no chrome a pagina ja esta compilada ... ja tem muita informação junta. interessante seria você efetuar o debug direto no visual studio

Comment: Seria interessante se você tivesse um link para aplicação.

Comment: @Otto, concordo sim e é isso que eu estou fazendo.

Comment: @pnet alguma evolução com o debug ?

Comment: @Otto, então o meu ambiente está bugado, mas estou debugando pelo c# e tirando os problemas que vão aparecendo. Acabei de postar um dificuldade, com chamada javascript, oriundo do debug. Está evoluindo sim.